# how to compile only one utility from binutils?

Tags: linux, makefile, binutils

New to makefiles and linux. How would I compile only readelf.c with all it's dependencies from binutils without compiling all of the other utilities? When trying `make binutils/readelf` i get the error: `sysdep.h:23:25: fatal error: alloca-conf.h: No such file or directory` when I try to do this. it requires some other dep?

Comment: there's no readelf make target

Comment: Sure there is (in `binutils-<version>/binutils/Makefile`).

Comment: What is up with these pairs of near-identical posts?  Twice tonight I have run across two different accounts posting the same question with the same error messages, but slightly different titles or problem statements.